# How to delete all system files using command prompt

Tags: cmd.exe

I want to know which cmd command can i use to delete all files on my computer(including all system files and especially the Windows folder).

Actually i want to clean my whole Hard drive and put new one.

I tried using del but it doesn't delete my system files.

Comment: You'd need to boot the system from other media. It's exceptionally difficult to remove the critical OS files of a running installation.

Comment: Agree... Go to recovery console or something and then try `FORMAT C: /fs:ntfs` or whatever drive the Windows installation is from there... see `FORMAT /?` for more detail but consider using the `/Q` switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the system is in use, you cannot delete the system files (for obvious reasons). Try installing a live CD such as [Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/) onto a USB, boot into that and use the tools on it to reformat and prepare your HDD. If you get confused, have a look around the documentation and information on the website linked, as there is plenty to go around.

So to answer your question, while you are booted into your system that you want to clear you CANNOT delete it via the command line. However, if you are not loaded into the system you want to clear you could use the command line command `del /S /F /Q C:\`. This command forces the deletion of read-only files, deletes all files in subdirectories and does not ask for confirmation. This is not a very good way to delete all your files, and doing some kind of format would be much more efficient in terms of time.